# Prevent Extension Methods from getting created

Tags: c#, .net

We have a very powerful feature called **Extension methods** with that you can add new methods to the class.

Here the question which I have is, Is there a way to prevent method from getting extended?
`

```
void Main()
{
    var test = new ClassA();
    Console.WriteLine(test.Test());
    Console.WriteLine(test.TestExt());//Extension method
}


public sealed class ClassA{
    public string Test(){
        return "hello";
    }
}

public static class ClassAExt{
    public static string TestExt(this ClassA testClass){
        return testClass.Test() + " Ext";
    }
}
```

`

Comment: We *don't add* methods to a class; *extension method* is a *syntax sugar*, we are just allowed to put `myObject.MyMethod();` instead of `MyExtension.MyMethod(myObject);`. And since we can't prevent implementing `static class MyExtension` with `MyMethod(this MyObject value)` method, we can't prevent extension methods

Comment: You don't extend a method, you add an extension method to a type. So an existing method cannot be extended in the sense that you do extension methods. If you wanna prevent override you can mark your method as sealed though.

Comment: what scenario are you trying to prevent here? understanding the "why" may help us guide you better (but: no, you can't stop someone adding extension methods to your type)

Comment: What is your problem? As long as your own "safe" code does not call those potentially "dangerous" methods everything is fine, isn´t it? The extension-method does not modify your own code in any way.

Comment: I am just curious to know if it is possible or not. We have sealed class which we use it to prevent class from getting inherited. In the same way wanted to know if there is something for Extension Method

Comment: Extension methods were explicitly invented to help programmers deal with classes that cannot be modified and still make their code easier to read.  They can not do anything that is not allowed by the class they extend.  Just syntax sugar, the readable version of a method that takes the class object as the 1st argument.  C# cannot stop you from writing such a method either.  Use the `internal` accessor specifier where appropriate.